# C++ will be struct as key for std::map copied to std::map?

Tags: c++, function, struct, scope

I have function in which I use struct as key for `std::map`. But I am not sure what will happen with that struct if I exit my function. Will be stored in `std::map` or will be deleted when exiting function scope and further search usage in `std::map` will be broken?

```
    //Map is standard class
    class Map { ... }

    //hashmap of maps
    std::map<Point, Map*> maps;

    void Maps::addMap(Map *map, int row, int column) {
      Point point = {row, column};
      maps[point] = map;
    }
```

EDIT :

Thanks to Thomas Sablik

I know that basic types like int are copied, but I did not know what happens by struct. If is copied then I am safe

EDIT 2

I changed my question, I did not know what to ask correctly to get my answer, sorry.

Comment: Here is a good read that should help you: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/value-semantics/

Comment: What is `maps`? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Perhaps refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) too.

Comment: what is Map? and Point? and maps?

Comment: `point` is copied. You can read most of it here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: Thank you, if it is copied then I am safe, this is what I need to know. Many thanks

Comment: BTW, there is a `map` symbol in the `std` namespace.  You may want to choose a different name.

Comment: Also, differentiating classes from variables by only case, e.g. `Map` vs. `map`, is poor coding style which can lead to confusion and injected defects.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector` instead of arrays.  Also, prefer passing by reference versus passing by pointer.  A pointer can point to anywhere, including invalid locations (and is difficult to validate).  A reference refers to an existing object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map` stores a copy of the key, regardless of the type of the key. While the local variable `point` is destroyed  at the end of `addMap`, `maps` is not destroyed, nor are its elements, which consist of the key and the value.

Answer (score 0):

point will be allocated on the stack, and shouldn't be accessed after addMap returns.
A pointer to Map will be added to maps at the position given by point. maps will still
have the entry after addMap returns. As you are adding pointers to maps you need to
be careful the memory pointed to persists for at least the lifetime of maps. As you come from Java, I suggest you double check.

Comment: Thank you, I placed this question because I am searching for random crash in my program and I was not sure with usage struct as key for std::map.